# Função javaScript não funciona quando usado ng-include angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou fazendo uma injeção de tamplate via `ng-include` do angularJs. 
Dentro desse template tenho um botão  que chama um modal o qual é inserido no template por outra injeção. Até então tudo funciona corretamente. Dentro do modal eu tenho uns inputs e um botão que deveria  inserir as informações na listagem, mas é isso que não funciona. Ele chama a função certo, passa os valores mas não insere na listagem. Vejamos o código.

```
app.controller("notasFiscaisProdutorLiquidacaoController", function($scope,$rootScope,$timeout){

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#btnAbrirModalNota").click(function(){
            jQuery("#modalAdicionarProduto").modal();
        });

        jQuery("#btnAbrirModalNotaLiquidacao").click(function(){
            jQuery("#modalAdicionarNotaLiquidacao").modal();
        });

    });

    $scope.etapa=1;
    $scope.primeiraEtapa='./arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimariaPaginas/notasFiscais/primeiraEtapa.html'
    $scope.segundaEtapa='./arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimariaPaginas/notasFiscais/segundaEtapa.html'
    $scope.terceiraEtapa='./arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimariaPaginas/notasFiscais/terceiraEtapa.html'

    $scope.proximaEtapa = function () {
        $scope.etapa++;
    }
    $scope.anterior = function () {
        $scope.etapa--;
    }


    $scope.notas=[];
    $scope.nota={};
    $scope.nota.flagARendimento="0";
    $scope.tipoNota="0";

    $scope.adicionarNota = function (fechar) {
        $scope.notas.push($scope.nota);
        $scope.nota={}
        if (fechar) {
            $('#modalAdicionarProduto').modal('hide');
        }
    };

});
```

Html principal

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<base href="/"></base>

<body>
<div ng-controller="notasFiscaisProdutorLiquidacaoController" class="voltar">
    <div class="col-md-12 " >
        <div ng-if="etapa==1" ng-include="primeiraEtapa"></div>
        <div ng-if="etapa==2" ng-include="segundaEtapa"></div>
        <div ng-if="etapa==3" ng-include="terceiraEtapa"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button style="color: black;" type="button" ng-click="anterior()" ng-disabled="etapa==1" class="btn btn-default btnFiscal" id="btnVoltar">Voltar </button>
                    <button style="color: black;" type="button" ng-click="proximaEtapa()" ng-disabled="etapa==3"class="btn btn-default btnFiscal" id="btnProximo">Próximo </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Template html

```
<div ng-controller="notasFiscaisProdutorLiquidacaoController" class="panel panel-primary container" id="containerEscolherEntidade">
    <div class="panel-heading container">Primeira etapa</div>

    <form novalidate name="frmNotasMultiplas" id="formCadastro1" role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div  class="col-md-12">

                <div class="row">
                    <div  class="col-md-12">
                        <div  class=" form-group col-md-3">
                            <label class="lb">Data emissão</label> <input ng-required="nota.idSituacao==1" type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="nota.dataEmissao" date-format />
                        </div>

                        <div  ng-show="tipoNota==0" class=" form-group col-md-3">
                        <label class="lb">Série</label>
                        <input ng-required="true" maxlength="3" type="text" class="form-control"
                              ng-model="nota.serie" />
                    </div>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <div ng-show="tipoNota==1" class=" form-group col-md-12 ">
                            <button type="button" id="btnAbrirModalProduto" class="btn btn-default" >Adicionar Produto </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div ng-show="tipoNota==1" class=" form-group col-md-12 ">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="lb">
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Série</th>
                            <th>Número</th>
                            <th>Opções</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="not in notas track by not.tipo">
                        <tr class="lb">
                            <td>{{not.tipo}}</td>
                            <td>{{not.serie}}</td>
                            <td>{{not.numero}}</td>
                        </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div ng-include="'./arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimariaPaginas/notasFiscais/modalAdicionarProdutoNota.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'./arrecadacao/producaoPrimaria/producaoPrimariaPaginas/notasFiscais/modalAdicionarProdutoNotaLiquidacao.html'"></div>

</div>
```

modal

```
<html>
<div  ng-controller="notasFiscaisProdutorLiquidacaoController">
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="modalAdicionarProduto" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <br> <br> <br> <br>
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div style="color: black; background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);" class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="limpaModalContadores()" >&times;</button>
                <h3>Produto</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form novalidate name="frmNota" id="formCadastro" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-md-6' >
                            <label class="lb">Tipo</label>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control"  ng-model="nota.tipo" style="width: 100%"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" >
                            <label class="lb">Série</label>
                            <input   type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nota.serie"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" >
                            <label class="lb">Número</label>
                            <input   type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nota.numero"  />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);">
                <button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btnSalvar1" id="btnSalvarRegistro" ng-click="adicionarNota(true)">Adicionar</button>
                <button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btnSalvar1" ng-click="adicionarNota(false)" id="btnSalvarModal" >Adicionar e novo</button>
                <button style="color: black;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btnCancelar closed" ng-click="limpaModalAdicionarNotas()" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está limpando o objeto `$scope.nota` com `$scope.nota={}`.

Tente fazer push com cópia assim:

```
$scope.notas.push(angular.copy($scope.nota));
```

Observei que você apenas exibe a listagem se `tipoNota==1`, não vejo em nenhum momento você atribuindo tipoNota para 1, ela é sempre 0.

Comment: não funcionou persiste o problema.

Comment: Observei que você apenas exibe a listagem se tipoNota==1, não vejo em nenhum momento você atribuindo tipoNota para 1, ela é sempre 0.

Answer (score 0):

Em todos os templates (principal, template e modal) o controller `notasFiscaisProdutorLiquidacaoController` é adicionado. Para o angular, toda vez que você adiciona um controller no `ng-controller` é criado uma nova instância. Talvez neste caso, seu script esteja tentando acessar uma variável que está em outro escopo (outra instância), segue um exemplo de controller adicionado duas vezes em um template:

```js
angular.module('teste',[]);
var test = angular.module('teste');
angular.module('teste').controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.someModel = {'value': 0}
  console.log('new instance');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="teste">
    <div>
      <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
          <input type="number" ng-model="someModel.value">
          <p></p>value in controller: {{someModel.value}}</p>
       </div>
       <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
          <input type="number" ng-model="someModel.value">
          <p></p>value in controller: {{someModel.value}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```